# programming 3d scene to STL file

Tags: 3d

I need to write 3d objects file for 3d printing. STL format.
I am programmer, not designer and I found 3d software like 3dmax and Blender too tricky.
What I looking for is some language (Perl, Python, CPP etc) library to create objects. Like

```
Cylinder cyl1 = new Cylinder(x,y, radius, heigh);
Box  mybox = new Box(x,y,x1,y1,);
scene->add(cyl1);         scene->add(mybox);     
scene->save("file.stl");
```

There should be standart shapes, adding, substracting (box with cylinder hole) rotating and scaling and may be reflecting capabilities.
I found POVray (have it's own special lang) and a lot of OpenGL libraries but no way to export their stuff to STL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to create 3D models using some APIs
Following are some of your options:

- https://github.com/kovacsv/JSModeler (Javascript support)
- http://www.spatial.com/products/cgm (Javascript support, For industrial use)
- http://www.openscenegraph.org/ (C++, not sure about STL export)

Also check out Autodesk website, they might have an app that could be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use numpy-stl package.

(http://pythonhosted.org/numpy-stl/usage.html#creating-mesh-objects-from-a-list-of-vertices-and-faces)

import numpy as np

from stl import mesh